# C# code to send exception caught in Biztalk

Tags: c#, email, smtp, biztalk

I have a C# code which catches exception in the Catch block. Currently I am just using System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf to log the error information and the Throw ex statements.

I need to catch the Transaction ID and send it across as a e-mail in my BizTalk code using C#. Any inputs please.

Comment: Can you show some code, so we see what you have?

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLineIf();
                throw ex;
            }

Comment: Where are you catching this exception?  Inside an orchestration?

Answer (score 0):

I would rethrow a custom exception that includes the Transaction ID, then Catch that in the BizTalk app.

There, you can handle it any way you want.

Let me ask, do you have any Event Log monitoring tools?